# C++11: How to get address / reference to outer class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose the following class (C++11):

```
class A
{
  int i;
  class B
  {
    void meth() 
    {
        // Get outer address / reference? 
    }; 
  } b;
};
```

**where `B` will always be part of `A`**, i.e. there is *no* code like `new B()`.

This means `b.meth()` will always operate with an outer `A`.

Question: How get to outer from `b.meth()` (which has always the same offset to `b` and that's known at compile time)?

Comment: Is `A` guaranteed to be a [standard layout class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType)?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/378784). What is the use case you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Inject it on construction... Give B a constructor and pass it along in that constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the best solution, and it's non-standard and I'm sure people will say it's a bad idea. **So, in case you just found this randomly on the Internet, don't use it blindly.** But I'm not sure that a standard solution even exists.

Here it goes:

```cpp
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

// This may not be needed if your compiler already has an offsetof macro defined
#ifndef offsetof
#define offsetof(s,m) ((::size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
#endif

class A
{
  public:
  int i;
  class B
  {
    public:
    void meth() 
    {
        // We basically subtract the offset of `b` within `A` from the start of `b`,
        // giving us the outer `A`'s `this`.
        A* outer = (A*)((std::uintptr_t)this - offsetof(A, b));
        std::cout << outer->i;
    }; 
  } b;
};


int main()
{
  A a;
  a.i = 123;
  a.b.meth();

  return 0;
}

// Output: 123
```

Note that this will fail if `A` is not a standard layout type.

Anyway I think you should think about a better way to model your data structure instead. What I posted is a band-aid for your immediate issue.

Comment: Hi, for now I am using `offsetof`. `A` has no virtual stuff, is not derived from anything and will not be derived from. And I am fine if the solution is implementation-defined.

Comment: And it's for g++ that has offsetof.

Comment: A better (as in, less hackish) solution may be storing a pointer to `A` inside `B` itself, and passing it there in `A`'s constructor.

Comment: That crashed. `A` currently has default copy constructor and assignment. For now I am preferring information known at compile time over passing around, storing and maintaining redundant data at run time.